# Why the image is not changing when I put mouse over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here in the line where the image team.gif is set, I have set events `onmouseout` and `onmouseover`, but both are not working. Image is not changing, when I put mouse over it. Please help me.

```
<div  id="about" style="position:absolute;top:1310px;width:1340px;height:655px;background-color:black;opacity:0.9">
<div style="position:absolute;top:140px;left:630px;border:thin solid #03c1cb;width:2px;height:460px " >
</div>
<img src="mission.gif" alt="mission" style="position:absolute;top:1400px;right:430px" />
<img src="vision.gif" alt="vision" style="position:absolute;top:1570px;right:420px" />
<img src="team.gif" alt="team" style="position:absolute;top:1610px;right:360px;z-index:100" onmouseover="lighton(this)" onmouseout="lightof(this)" />
<img src="3.gif" alt="light"  id ="light"style="position:absolute;top:1360px;right:15px" />
</div>
```

my javascript code is here

```
<script>

lighton(x)
{
x.src="team1.gif";

}
lightof(x)
{
x.src="team.gif";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `script` you need to add the `function` keyword.

```
<script>

function lighton(x)
// ^^^^^^^^
{
x.src="team1.gif";

}
function lightof(x)
//^^^^^^^^
{
x.src="team.gif";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="team.gif" alt="team" style="position:absolute;top:1610px;right:360px;z-index:100"  onmouseover="this.src='team1.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='team.gif'" />
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8wx8r9za/